# Access a variable by name defined in a parent function from a nested function

Tags: python, scope

Is there a way to use something like `globals()` or `locals()` to access a variable defined in a parent function by name (i.e., as a string)?

Both of these examples give `KeyError: 'x'`:

```
def f(): 
    x = 1 
    def g(): 
        print(globals()['x']) 
    g()

def f(): 
    x = 1 
    def g(): 
        print(locals()['x']) 
    g()
```

Comment: `x` is neither a global nor a local variable. You'd have to inspect the stack frame. Honestly, there is almost certainly no reason to do this. What are you *actually* trying to accomplish? IOW, you can probably accomplish this, but you probably don't really want to.

Comment: @heemayl The context is looping through a set of variable names. It could probably be done better with a dict but I'm looking for a minimal refactor from existing code and am generally curious if it's possible.

Comment: Why not use a dictionary to define your variables as key, and perform dict lookup

Comment: As I said, I understand a dict would be better practice, but I'm curious if this is possible.

Comment: Why not go with the better practice, also `x` is not a local or a global variable in either of the two definitions, for the first def to work, x needs to be defined in a global scope, for the second def to work, x needs to be defined inside g

Comment: If you'd like to provide an answer saying this is not possible, I'll accept it pending further input confirming so. But I'd like to keep the question to the original scope (no pun intended).

Comment: Also, the code you provide does not show WHY you would do this. You said it is to refactor existing code without too much modification. But when the code will be bad after the refactoring you shouldn't do this. Remember: Beautiful is better than ugly and simple is better than complex. Where does 'x' come from and why access it by it's name as string? This example does'nt make much sense for me.

Comment: I provided a minimal reproducible example, as suggested in StackOverflow guidelines.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Yes it's possible, but you are working against Python, don't do this:

```
In [1]: import inspect

In [2]: def f():
   ...:     x = 1
   ...:     def g():
   ...:         print(inspect.currentframe().f_back.f_locals['x'])
   ...:     g()
   ...:

In [3]: f()
1
```

Seriously, don't. Write good code, not bad code. For all of us.

Answer (score 1):

I'm not really sure about it's usefullness, but you can do this by inspecting the stack frame of the enclosing function i.e. frame at depth 1 and getting `x` from the `locals` dict:

```
In [1]: import sys

In [2]: def f():
   ...:     x = 1
   ...:     def g():
   ...:         print(sys._getframe(1).f_locals['x'])
   ...:     g()
   ...:    
In [3]: f()
1
```

Answer (score 0):

Why not just pass the value to the child function like this:

```
def f(): 
    x = 1 
    def g(parameter): 
        print(parameter) 
    g(x)
```

Comment: I need to access `'x'` as a string.